# convert Pandas dataframe into adjacency matrix

Tags: python, pandas, adjacency-matrix

I have a Pandas dataframe (930 rows × 50 columns) that looks like this:

| index | Keyword A | Keyword B | Keyword c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Page 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| Page 2 | 4 | 0 | 2 |
| Page 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I would like to convert it into an adjacency Matrix / Weighted Graph, where each Keyword is a node. The weight would be the sum of combinations between each keywords.

The result would be something along these lines:

|  | Keyword A | Keyword B | Keyword C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Keyword A | 0 | 3 | 8 |
| Keyword B | 3 | 0 | 4 |
| Keyword C | 8 | 4 | 0 |

Comment: What is the output in this case?

Comment: I updated the question so you can see the expected output.

Comment: What are the rules to count? How do you get the number for  `Keyword B | Keyword A` is 3?

Comment: Keyword B : Keyword C should be 6, right?

Comment: A:C should be `9 = (1*1 + 4*2 + 0*1)`.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is deceptively simple:

```
adj = df.T @ df
np.fill_diagonal(adj.values, 0)
```

E.g.:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 3, 1], [2, 4, 0, 2], [3, 0, 1, 1]],
                      columns=["index", "A", "B", "C"]).set_index("index")
>>> df
       A  B  C
index
1      1  3  1
2      4  0  2
3      0  1  1
>>> adj = df.T @ df
>>> np.fill_diagonal(adj.values, 0)
>>> adj
   A  B  C
A  0  3  9
B  3  0  4
C  9  4  0
```